# When is it too late to optimize for performance?

Tags: performance, database-design, optimization

I know that you shouldnt optimize too early, and you should instead aim for maintainability. My question is, at what point is it too late?

I'm working on a website, similar to yahoo answers, and my database structure is exactly what I feel it should be. Table for `users`, `questions`, `answers`, `question_comments`, `answer_comments`, etc.

My question is, IF the site were to grow, how would this architecture scale? I'm thinking of putting both questions and answers in a single table (`posts`), separating them by type, and then putting both question_comments and answer_comments in the same table (`comments`). I believe this is similar to stackoverflow's DB scheme.

I know what you guys are gonna say, "Dont worry about it until it becomes an actual problem". But wouldn't it be a little too late to worry about it then?

Thanks

Comment: It's never 'too late', it's always 'how much it will cost' :)

Comment: You can always restructure it, right? It might be harder later on, but doing it now makes getting there harder ;)

Comment: A database structure != an architecture

Comment: it's never too late to turn back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's a bad practice to optimize early is you **don't know where your bottlenecks will be** until your website sees a significant amount of traffic. How your users access and interact with your site is an unknown at this point.

It's almost always best to start with a 'good' architecture (normalized database, MVC architecture, DRY, well-written frontend code, etc) and go from there. It will be much easier to scale a clean, organized architecture than one that was prematurely optimized.

At best right now you can do some load testing via [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) or another load testing tool to see where your current bottlenecks are. It certainly won't find all of them, but it will find some.

If you're really worried about this (and you shouldn't be yet), install [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) on your server to monitor performance. Use a third party tool to measure page load time daily. Once you start seeing issues then you can profile and tune.

Comment: Ryan has it absolutely right! Until you have at least your basic architecture in place, you do not know where your bottlenecks are. Optimization is an iterative and continual process, ideally building on refactoring, that involves measurement and improvement of your code.

Comment: This isn't always true (even if it is my initial view) -- for instance, (high-performance!) game development/developers should already be aware of the bottlenecks from the start; not that micro-optimizations should be done initially but that this *very performance critical* design needs to be considered from the start. Of course, when I write my desktop apps then ... different story :)

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should optimize if a fast service is a fundamental requirement of the application.

If sub-second responses are not a requirement, than you can write clean code and optimize later.

A good example of this was JavaScript before the latest version of browsers, people who wrote nice, clean, extensible JS for their pages had terrible performance and had to start from scratch.

Comment: (1) _'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.'_ (2) Were prototype.js or Dojo full of terrible hacks before Spidermonkey and V8 arrived?

Answer (score 0):

One huge table is generally harder to maintain. People usually cut their tables into partitions and even their databases into shards.

I don't see how putting all comments into the same table would save you a join. Really, putting questions and answers into the same table won't save you a join either, you'll just be joining by the same table.

If you want to save on joins, I'd expect you use a document-oriented NoSQL database, such as MongoDB. That's where you can store a question with all related answers and comments in a single 'record', fetchable with one operation.

Answer (score 0):

Databases need to be designed with performance in mind not wait until you havea problem later. Premature optimization doesn't mean don't do it in design, it means don't get ridiculously excessive about it. However, there are known performance killers for every database backend and it is foolish to design to use one of those when a differnt technique will be faster and take the same amount of time to write code for if you are familar with it. So before designing any database, read up on performance tuning and you will never write database code the same way again.